# Clearing Buefy datepicker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, prop, buefy

I have a value deliveryDate which is gotten from my beufy date picker. I have a clear button connected that should change the date to null when clicked, so that no date is picked. The issue with this is that I am getting error's in the console about prop type. My datepicker is set up as below.

```
                 <b-datepicker
                  v-model="deliveryDate"
                  expanded
                  :min-date="minDate"
                  placeholder="Click to select"
                  :mobile-native="false"
                  @input="updateDeliveryDate"
                ></b-datepicker>
                <b-button
                  icon-left="close"
                  type="is-primary"
                  @click="clearDeliveryDate"
                ></b-button>
```

deliveryDate is saved in my vuex store, so when updateDeliveryDate is called it dispatches the date to my store. When clearDeliveryDate is called it dispatches the value null to my store. But then when I refresh the page, I get the console error : [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Date, Array, got String with value "2020-08-14T07:00:00.000Z". By default I set deliveryDate to null in the store. If I completely remove the v-model then it updates my value properly but the datepicker won't display the change from a date to null (the placeholder). Any ideas would be great as I have been stuck for a while trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <b-button icon-left="close" type="is-primary" @click="deliveryDate = null"></b-button>
```